# How to pass data from parent to child controller using angular $broadcast?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass id argument to child controller using angular `$broadcast` but with below code i am not able to achieve that task any idea what is implemented wrong ?

ParentCtrl.js

```
 $scope.deleteXml = function(id, toast) {
     var id = $scope.diagramObj._id;
     var modalInstance = buildModal(null, 'delete');
     modalInstance.result.then(function(user) {
         //$scope.users.push(user);
     }, function() {
         //$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
     });
     $rootScope.$broadcast('delete-diagram', id);
     $scope.refreshDiagrams;

 }
```

ChildCtrl.js

```
$rootScope.$on('delete-diagram', function(event, id) {
                console.log(id);
             });
```

Comment: try to breadcast an object, not an id { id: id}

Comment: show `html` with hierarchies of those controllers

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. However you also need to destroy $rootScope event.

Ex.

```
    $rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent',$scope.data);

   var customeEventListener = $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data) {

  }
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        customeEventListener();
  });
```

or,

It is better to use $scope.$on as listeners on $scope are destroyed automatically i.e. as soon as $scope is destroyed.

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data) {}
```

Comment: Even changing to `$scope.$on` still not getting the data in child controller

Comment: what are you getting inside console?

Comment: its not printing anything

Comment: Can you tell me what you get: console.log("MY ID"id); Are you able to see MY ID inside console?

Comment: in console i do not see `id` printed infact there is no error

Comment: So basically, your event is not fired . Syntax is correct. Reason for this problem is different. Either both your controller is not in a same module

Comment: both controllers are in same module.